# Does row interchange affect the positive-definiteness of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

I want to know if I do a row interchange on a positive definite matrix, will the result also be positive definite? And conversely, if I do a row interchange on a matrix that is not positive definite, will the resultant also not be positive definite?
Or can the row interchange change the positive definiteness status of a matrix?

Comment: I suspect by *resultant* you mean *result*. Resultant has a specific definition for polynomials.

Comment: If you interchange two rows without interchanging the respective columns, the resulting matrix in general will not be Hermitian and you cannot even speak of its definiteness.

Comment: @user1551 yes you are right about that? What if we were to interchange the corresponding columns as well. What would happen to the definiteness then?

Comment: @MollieVX If you use the same permutation to permute the rows and columns of the matrix, you are just reordering the basis. The definiteness (or the lack of it) is not affected.

Comment: note that a row interchange only changes the sign of the determinant.  A positive definite matrix necessarily has a positive determinant...

Comment: @user1551 Why is that true?

Comment: @user3180 If $P$ is a permutation matrix and $A$ is Hermitian, then the statement  $\langle Ax,x\rangle>0$ for all $x\ne0$ is equivalent to $\langle (P^TAP)Px,Px\rangle>0$ for all $x\ne0$. Since $x\ne0$ iff $y=Px\ne0$, the aforementioned statement is further equivalent to $\langle (P^TAP)y,y\rangle>0$ for all $y\ne0$. Hence $A$ is positive definite if and only if $P^TAP$ is positive definite. Similar conclusions hold if positive definiteness is replaced by pos. semidefiniteness, neg. definiteness or neg. semidefiniteness. It also follows that $A$ is indefinite iff $P^TAP$ is indefinite.